# NiFi: Configuring SSLContext, Truststore or Keystore Certification

Tags: ssl, apache-nifi, http-status-code-401

I am trying to get data from the [DC Metro's API tool](https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/). I am using the "Train Position" link.

I need to configure my `SSLContextService`, but I only have a Primary and Secondary key provided by the website. For example, the keys are in this form:

```
5bcf1f7d091f4f618f1eefbefe23a56e
f15633bd2dd44a1f944c96361c0ab26f
```

How do I configure this in the `SSLContext` part of NiFi? I am using `GetHTTP`. Here is a picture of what I currently have, first the `GetHTTP` config and then the `SSL` config:

[image]

Next Config:

[image]

I have no idea how to use those keys above as the `Truststore` or `Keystore`, or if that's even what I'm supposed to do. I have my Keystore filename pointed at `cacerts`, but I know those keys are not in there. I've tried to convert them to `.pem`, and that was a mistake, especially when I put them in `keystore.jks`.

I get this error:

[image]

How do I get access?

Useful [link on API link](https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/5763fa6ff91823096cac1057/operations/5763fb35f91823096cac1058).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that API keys as you've given are considered sensitive information just like a password.

These keys are used to access the *API*, and are unrelated to NiFi keystore/truststores which are used for SSL negotiation. Using Java cacerts in this case is correct but you do not need to add an API key to a truststore.

This page describes the form the request needs to take: https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/5763fa6ff91823096cac1057/operations/5763fb35f91823096cac1058#TrainPosition

I suggest you read into how to use web APIs and making web requests to then understand how your API keys are used. They give an example curl at the bottom:

```html
curl -v -X GET "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType={contentType}"
-H "api_key: {subscription key}"

--data-ascii "{body}"
```

The {subscription key} is your API key, the {contentType} is the HTTP response content type. If you're unfamiliar with these terms you may need to look into them. I recommend getting the above curl command to work first, then carry that across to NiFi.

curl -v -X GET "api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json" -H "api_key: e13626d03d8e4c03ac07f95541b3091b" works for me. (This is a test API key from wmata website).

In InvokeHTTP, you would add a processor property (hit the plus symbol top right) called 'api_key' with the value set to your subscriber key (I don't know if this is the primary key), and set the "Attributes to Send" property value to "api_key". This will send the api_key attribute (the key) as a header called api_key just as we did above in curl with -H "api_key: e136... ".

Comment: I've since regenerated the keys - I just didn't know a good way to illustrate what I was getting at. Thanks

Comment: Would my primary key be the subscription key? the `curl` command works in my terminal, but otherwise I get a 401

Comment: All I get is 404's saying my subscription is invalid, and I've even used the practice one they provide for people who haven't signed up yet. And I have figured out the contentType, thanks.

Comment: curl -v -X GET "https://api.wmata.com/TrainPositions/TrainPositions?contentType=json" -H "api_key: e13626d03d8e4c03ac07f95541b3091b"

works for me. In InvokeHTTP, you would add a processor property (hit the plus symbol top right) called 'api_key' with the value set to your subscriber key (I don't know if this is the primary key), and set the "Attributes to Send" property value to "api_key". This will send the api_key attribute (the key) as a header called api_key  just as we did above in curl with -H "api_key: e136... ".

Comment: Unreal. Thank you. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Updated original comment

Comment: @returntosender404 Can you store an API key as a sensitive parameter in NiFi and how?